During Amazon smarthome development, using fireTV 4K 2nd screen projector, rtsp stream digest authentication failed, no realm
As mentioned in the title, our screencast stream is rtsp://admin:111111@abc.abc.net:443/stream. It has been confirmed that the discovery was successful and the flow address was obtained successfully.
When fetching the stream, the server also received the rtsp request, and the server requires digest-md5 authentication. At this time we found that during digest, the screen mirror sent Digest nonce="2cc45dee70e7211f4110698f62962991c04a9c97839200dc902c22011220ce93", username="admin", uri="rtsp:abc.abc.net:443/stream", response="3ddae088a4c 1021931f54a68609ef8f7"
The realm sent by the server is not carried, causing the authentication to fail.
Has anyone encountered similar problems?
We found it on fireTV 4K 2nd and we saw its os is 8.1.0.3. This stream was successful in the past.

Can you clarify how the question relates to MongoDB Realm? The question has the MongoDB Realm tag - do you have some example code that's not working? Please take a moment and review How to ask a question and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
